# View images on CompactFlash on iPadPro using Lightning to USB 3 adapter?

Tags: ipad

With my Canon WiFi-enabled DSLR, while on location I'm able to wirelessly copy stills to my iPad Pro and view the shots on the iPad Pro.

I'm trying to do same with my WiFi-less Canon DSLR.

Is this possible by inserting the CF card in a card reader connected to "Apple Lightning to USB 3" accessory which is then plugged into the iPad Pro.

a) What is your experience with this setup?
and 
b) What is another alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple says](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter):

> Add even greater capability and versatility to your iPad Pro by powering the Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter with a USB Power Adapter. Then you can connect USB peripherals like hubs, Ethernet adapters, audio/MIDI interfaces, and card readers for CompactFlash, SD, microSD, and more.

It sounds like using a USB card reader is supported. However, you may need to plug a USB-C power adapter in to your Lightning->USB3 adapter to get it to work. Thankfully there are USB-C battery packs if you want to stay mobile.

Comment: Note for posterity: the cable worked reliably on iOS 10 but after not after upgrade to iOS 11. Complained about insufficient power even with original Apple  power cable connected. Also, notice random missing files and interrupted/incomplete copying of files to iPad 12.9 inch (2nd generation) when it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how the setup would work with the CF in card reader connected to the iPad would work nor do I have that camera, but there are a few alternatives that might work...

- Moving the CF card to the WiFi enabled camera and forcing it to sync if you can
- Use an Android phone or tablet that has OTG support (majority do) and using the adapter
- Use a laptop or desktop if that's what it comes down to then you can transfer them to the iPad (possibly by email)

If the USB-lightning adapter supports USB storage devices, it should work fine with the CF card in the card reader

Hope this helped